# Could not find RubyGem bundler only by cap

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano

this my forst deployment trial for rails.

I managed to setup all dependencies in the server side

when I type

```
bundle exec rails console
```

everything works fine. I got this strange problem when I run cap deploy:migrations locally

```
[.com] sh -c 'cd /home//.com/releases/20120411120423 && bundle     install --gemfile /home//.com/releases/20120411120423/Gemfile --path /home//.com/shared/bundle --deployment --quiet --without development test'
** [out ::.com] /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:779:in `report_activate_error':     Could not find RubyGem bundler (>= 0) (Gem::LoadError
** [out ::.com] )
** [out ::.com] from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:214:in `activate'
** [out ::.com] from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:1082:in `gem'
** [out ::.com] from /home//.gems/bin/bundle:18
command finished in 539ms
```

when I copy the command manually and execute it in the server it works perfectly!

this is my deploy.rb file

```
require "bundler/capistrano"

default_run_options[:pty] = true
set :user, 'xyz'
set :domain, 'xyz.com'
set :application, 'xyz'

set :repository,  "#{user}@#{domain}:git/#{application}.git"
set :deploy_to, "/home/#{user}/#{domain}"
set :deploy_via, :remote_cache
set :scm, 'git'
set :branch, 'master'
set :git_shallow_clone, 1
set :scm_verbose, true
set :use_sudo, false

set :rake, "/home//.gems/bin/rake"

server domain, :app, :web
role :db, domain, :primary => true

namespace :deploy do
  task :restart do
  run "touch #{current_path}/tmp/restart.txt"
   end
end
```

update:

when I launch the bundle -v from cap I got the correct location!

```
$ cap invoke COMMAND="which bundle"
```

output

```
 /home//.gems/bin/bundle
```

Comment: by the way I searched stackoverflow questions and no one helped me :( this is so important.

Answer (score 0):

adding those lines to config.ru file solved the problem

```
ENV['GEM_HOME'] = '/home/aaalsubaie/.gems/'
ENV['GEM_PATH'] = '/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8'

require 'rubygems'
Gem.clear_paths
```